# How to use the condensed format of the OpenSans font

Tags: fonts

I would like to use the following formatting of the OpenSans font which are available according to the samples that are provided [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/opensans/doc/fonts/opensans):

- OpenSansCondensed-Light
- OpenSansCondensed-Bold
- OpenSansCondensed-LightItalic

The font can easily be integrated using the `opensans` package, but how can I access the above formatting? Could anyone provide an example? Thanks for your help!

This is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{opensans}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example showing what you've got and be a bit more specific about what you want? Do you just want to be able to switch to condensed? Do you want to use it as the default sans serif font? Or what?

Comment: There is no condensed bold as far as I can see. Where did you find mention of this?

Comment: I added a working example. Google lists a condensed bold version here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed

Comment: A condensed bold may be available, but is not in the LaTeX package. All you can do in this case is (1) not use condensed bold, (2) create your own support files for it or (3) send the package maintainer a feature request, asking her/him to add support for condensed bold in a future update. The other option you have is to install the font family for your OS and use LuaTeX or XeTeX (rather than pdfTeX or TeX) with `fontspec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the light series using `\fontseries{lc}\selectfont` where `lc` stands for `l`ight `c`ondensed.
All fontseries can be found in the [documentation for opensans at CTAN (page 5)](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/fonts/opensans/doc/opensans.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{opensans}
\begin{document}
\fontseries{lc}\selectfont

Condensed

\textit{Condensed Italic}

\fontseries{bc}\selectfont
Condensed Bold
\end{document}
```

[image: graphical presentation of the code example above]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, although the package makes the fonts available, it does not provide a convenient user interface. This is unfortunate because the author of the package is in the best position to provide this. Hence, the following might have unintended consequences as a result of the details of the font configuration. That said, it seems to work OK in minimal testing on Kant's metaphysics.

## *Caveat emptor*

First, we provide `\clseries` to switch to condensed, light. This will be ignored if the current family is not `fos`. If you are using hanging figures, substitute `fosj` for `fos`.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\clseries{%
  \not@math@alphabet\clseries\relax
  \edef\tempa{\f@family}\edef\tempb{fos}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \fontseries{cl}\selectfont
  \fi
}
```

Then we do the same for the semi-bold series. There is no condensed bold. However, the straight bold probably looks too much with light as the contrast, so try this instead. Alternatively, you could substitute the regular weight medium (`m`) for bold.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{%
  \not@math@alphabet\sbseries\relax
  \edef\tempa{\f@family}\edef\tempb{fos}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \fontseries{sb}\selectfont
  \fi
}
```

Now provide `\textXX` macros which, as with similar macros, will set their argument in condensed light or semi-bold, as the case may be.

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textcl{\clseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textsb{\sbseries}
```

Then it is straightforward to utilise these series in a document.

[image: sampler]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultsans]{opensans}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\clseries{%
  \not@math@alphabet\clseries\relax
  \edef\tempa{\f@family}\edef\tempb{fos}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \fontseries{cl}\selectfont
  \fi
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\sbseries{%
  \not@math@alphabet\sbseries\relax
  \edef\tempa{\f@family}\edef\tempb{fos}%
  \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \fontseries{sb}\selectfont
  \fi
}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textcl{\clseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand\textsb{\sbseries}
\makeatother
\newcommand\testtext{As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be used as a canon for our understanding. }

\begin{document}
{%
  \sffamily
  {%
    \clseries
    \testtext
    \itshape
    \testtext
    \scshape
    \testtext
    \upshape
    \testtext
  }%
  Antelopes and \textcl{aardvarks}\par
  {%
    \sbseries
    \testtext
    \itshape
    \testtext
    \scshape
    \testtext
    \upshape
    \testtext
  }%  
  Antelopes and \textsb{aardvarks}
}
\end{document}
```